# New style of cart button when item is in cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I use a code that changes the text of the "Add to Cart" button for a product if the item is already in the cart.

```php
/* for single product */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'single_product_button_text' );
 
function single_product_button_text( $text ) {
 
    if( WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( get_the_ID() ) ) ) {
        $text = 'Product in cart';
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}
 
/* for archive/category pages */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'products_button_text', 20, 2 );
 
function products_button_text( $text, $product ) {
 
    if( 
       $product->is_type( 'simple' )
       && $product->is_purchasable()
       && $product->is_in_stock()
       && WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() ) )
    ) {
 
        $text = 'Product in cart';
 
    }
 
    return $text;
 
}
```

Tell me how you can change the style of the "Add to Cart" button for a product if the product has already been added to the cart?

I tried adding code to /loop/add-to-cart.php file as shown here [Change add to cart button style when product is in cart in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969767/change-add-to-cart-button-style-when-product-is-in-cart-in-woocommerce) but it doesn't work for me.

Are there any other code options that would help resolve my question?

I will be glad for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to check via `jQuery` whether a certain element (your add-to-cart button) contains a certain text, if this is the case, we will add an extra class that you can style via `CSS`.

[:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) - Select all elements that contain the specified text.

So you get:

```
function action_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var selector = '.add_to_cart_text:contains("Product in cart")';
            
            // Selector contains specific text
            if ( $( selector ).length > 0 ) {
                $( selector ).addClass( 'product-is-added' );
            } else {
                $( selector ).removeClass( 'product-is-added' );            
            }
            
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer' );
```

---

**Note:** The selector (class) can be named differently depending on the theme you are using

Comment: Nice solution. Congratulations for receiving the woocommerce golden badge and reaching to 20k. Thanks for sharing your expertise with us. I've personally learned a lot from you.

Comment: @Ruvee Thank you. Don't worry, I'm still in a learning process too. What seems good code today will be outdated tomorrow. Although I still do this as a hobby and not professionally, I do have plans to develop free plugins that extend WooCommerce. 
I recently wrote my first theme for WordPress/WooCommerce completely from scratch, it was fun! After all, we are here to learn from each other ;-) keep up the good work!

Comment: That's great! I should definitely try that theme. That theme should be a fantastic theme, I have no doubt. Please feel free to share a link to the theme if it's available as well as that plugin when it's ready. Looking forward to trying them all, thanks, And congrats again on your new achievements.